# Dynamic Form (knockout.js) data to PayPal

Tags: php, knockout.js, paypal

So I am learning KnockoutJS at the moment and I built a dynamic order form/cart with multiple product options, discounts, tax rates based on location and more. I am quite satisfied with the result and Knockout and general.
Now I want to take it one step further and implement PayPal as a payment option and I am somehow totally lost. The PayPal developer pages are super confusing, I cant even find a real starting point.
My KnockoutJS "app" returns JSON with all the computed data. How can I (securely) send this data to PayPal and initiate the actual payment process?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try using one of the paypal exemples with hardcoded JSON and once you get that working hook up knockout to it.

Comment: This http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html was the primer i was looking for and helped me alot!